# ConEmu and console SSH clients that produce raw output (no ANSI escapes processed)

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty, conemu, plink

I use PuTTY daily and I use ConEmu heavily too (the latter mostly for Far Manager). A week ago I stopped using MTPuTTY in order to put PuTTY directly into ConEmu (because MTPuTTY grabs focus too aggressively making me to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> at least twice to switch to another application; awesome ConEmu Quake-style console support and much more; etc). However, PuTTY is a GUI application and its configuration does not match ConEmu configuration + PuTTY does not allow to use some hotkeys I expected to use in ConEmu.

The reason of why PuTTY is a GUI application is pretty obvious: being implemented as a GUI application it can overcome the Windows console subsystem limitations. But ConEmu overcomes these limitations as well so I started looking for a SSH client that could work in the Windows console subsystem so that ConEmu could intercept and improve it. Solutions like Win32-OpenSSH do not really work because they already process ANSI escape codes and try to align the codes with the Windows console limitations (if I'm not mistaken, `AnsiColors256.ans`, from the ConEmu distributive, just renders almost nothing when using Win32-OpenSSH).

I also tried using `plink.exe`, and it does not seem to process ANSI escape codes so that ConEmu can processes ANSI escape codes itself. This seems to be what I'm looking for... But there are many restrictions too: cursor and functional keys are just ignored, `mc` renders very messy (no frame chars, it can't detect window size, etc). Anyway, my custom hotkeys are no longer blocked and ConEmu configuration now works fine in its real-console-based tabs!

Is it possible to use ConEmu with `plink.exe` (or probably something else) somehow so that I could stop using PuTTY? Or am I just mixing the concepts and trying to combine these applications in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install cygwin or msys2 or git-for-windows. In Windows 10 you may also use Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.
2. Install latest ConEmu alpha build.
3. ConEmu will create new default tasks for new bash shells using connector.

Just run them and run ssh.

---

In the past I made a [plink fork](https://github.com/Maximus5/plink) where some problems were fixed (arrow keys, etc.), but it still is not perfect for daily use.

Win32-OpenSSH has many problems too.

That's why preferred solution is [connector](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html) and [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) or [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) implementation of ssh client. [Git-for-Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) based on msys2 is OK too.

Comment: Thank you for doing an AMAZING job with ConEmu! I was trying to follow your instructions but none of them work to me. Why? No clue what I was doing wrong. To be honest, I find it too heavy: I would like to abandon PuTTY, and definitely would not like to get into heavier solutions like slow Cygwin or its alternatives. Anyway, your `plink` fork is great. and I really think that it is what all Windows SSH users miss. It would be also nice if PuTTY could work with Windows consoles and not process special ANSI output (possible in principle?). Windows is still everlasting suffering.